# How do I store line-breaks from textarea properly in mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, textarea

I've been having this issue with submitting and storing textarea content, to which I've been unable to find a proper solution.

I have a form, with a textarea field, called "description".

When I submit the form with multiline text, like

> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3

It gets stored in the mySQL db with much more new lines. It becomes :-

> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3

when I check the db with phpmyadmin.

I've tried both VARCHAR and TEXT types, its the same. What do I need to do to store the textarea content accurately?

The relevant codeigniter lines are
aRow[$strField] = strip_tags($this->input->post($strField));
$this->db->insert($this->strTable, $aRow);

$strField will be my textarea field, and the insert is a CI function.

Comment: Have you used the `mysql_real_escape_string` function?

Comment: i believe CI has already handled that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay I've found the answer. I'm using CI 2.0, and it is an existing bug that has already been reported.
https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/issue/332/newlines-in-textareas-are-duplicated

The quick fix is as below (look for the file in /system/core/Input.php)

```
//$str = str_replace(array( "\r\n", "\r"), PHP_EOL, $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(?:\r\n|[\r\n])/', PHP_EOL, $str);
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: I really should keep up to date - but this got me today. Proper fix is [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/82f9b1571370e8d87a0cbd4ff16647a6eccf3c6e) which should be in version 2.0.2

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a newline is being added after each new line. This has to do with how the data is inserted into the database. Care to share that code?

Comment: I'm using codeigniter. The relevant lines are $aRow[$strField] = strip_tags($this->input->post($strField)); $this->db->insert($this->strTable, $aRow);

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with codeignighter. I suspect the problem is with $this->input->post(), but that's as much as I can say. I suggest editing the original post to include this line of code - it will be very helpful when a codenighter pro comes along!

Answer (score 0):

try to use \n in database and when you showing record use `nl2br()`

[for more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: showing records are fine, yes i use nl2br. the problem is when i submit the form data into the db (it is already stored with the extra lines)